# Is it possible to integrate a TWA into a React Native project?

Tags: react-native, progressive-web-apps, twa

I am wondering if it is possible to integrate [TWA (Trusted Web Activities)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa) into an existing React Native project. This way I could have a section in my app where costumers can use my PWA inside my app. As fallback for iOS I would use something like their WebView. If it is possible, how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: I have the same question :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, it is possible to integrate Trusted Web Activity into a React Native App.

You'd need to create an [Android Native Module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) that wraps [Android Browser Helper](http://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper) into a React Native API. Since you want to use the Trusted Web Activity as part of your app, you will probably be looking into wrapping [TwaLauncher](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/blob/master/androidbrowserhelper/src/main/java/com/google/androidbrowserhelper/trusted/TwaLauncher.java).

Then, you will need to implement a [module for iOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios), which will have the same API in React, but will use the WebView as an implementation.

It seems someone has [already created a wrapper for Android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-trusted-web-activity) (but I haven't tested).